# Sprint Cloud Dataflow with Kubernetes: BackoffLimit

Tags: spring, kubernetes, spring-cloud-dataflow

**Kubernetes Pod backoff failure policy**

From the [k8s documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/):

> There are situations where you want to fail a Job after some amount of retries due to a logical error in configuration etc. To do so, set .spec.backoffLimit to specify the number of retries before considering a Job as failed. The back-off limit is set by default to 6.

**Spring cloud dataflow:**

When a job has failed, we actually don't want a retry. In other words, we want to set the `backoffLimit: 1` in our Sprint Cloud Dataflow config file.

We have tried to set it like the following:

```
deployer.kubernetes.spec.backoffLimit: 1
```

or even

```
deployer.kubernetes.backoffLimit: 1
```

But both is not transmitted to our Kubernetes Cluster.

After 6 tries, we see the following message:

> status:   conditions:
>       - lastProbeTime: '2019-10-22T17:45:46Z'
>         lastTransitionTime: '2019-10-22T17:45:46Z'
>         message: Job has reached the specified backoff limit
>         reason: BackoffLimitExceeded
>         status: 'True'
>         type: Failed   failed: 6   startTime: '2019-10-22T17:33:01Z'

Actually we want to fail fast (1 or 2 tries maximum)

Question: How can we properly set this property, so that all task triggered by SCDF will fail maximum once on Kubernetes?

**Update (23.10.2019)**

We have also tried the property:

```
deployer:
   kubernetes:
      maxCrashLoopBackOffRestarts: Never # No retry for failed tasks
```

But the jobs are still failing 6 times instead of 1.

**Update (26.10.2019)**

For completeness sake:

1. I am scheduling a task in SCDF
2. The task is triggered on Kubernetes (more specifically Openshift)
3. When I check the configuration on the K8s-platform, I see that it still has a backoffLimit of 6, instead of 1:

Yalm config snippet taken from the running pod:

```
  spec:
    backoffLimit: 6
    completions: 1
    parallelism: 1
```

In the official [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_tasks), it says:

```
`maxCrashLoopBackOffRestarts` - Maximum allowed restarts for app that is in a CrashLoopBackOff. Values are `Always`, `IfNotPresent`, `Never`
```

But `maxCrashLoopBackOffRestarts` takes an integer. So I guess the documentation is not accurate.

The pod is then restarted 6 times.

I have tried to set those properties unsuccessfully:

```
spring.cloud.dataflow.task.platform.kubernetes.accounts.defaults.maxCrashLoopBackOffRestarts: 0
spring.cloud.deployer.kubernetes.maxCrashLoopBackOffRestarts: 0
spring.cloud.scheduler.kubernetes.maxCrashLoopBackOffRestarts: 0
```

None of those has worked.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to ilayaperumalg it's much clearer why it's not working:

> It looks like the property maxCrashLoopBackOffRestarts is applicable
>   for determining the status of the runtime application instance while
>   the property you refer to as backoffLimit is applicable to the JobSpec
>   which is currently not being supported. We can add this as a feature
>   to support your case.

[Github Link](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer-kubernetes/issues/332)

Answer (score 0):

To override the default restart limit, you'd have to use SCDF's `maxCrashLoopBackOffRestarts` deployer property. All of the supported properties are documented in the [ref. guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-kubernetes-deployer).

You can configure to override this property "globally" in SCDF or individually override it at each stream/task deployment level, as well. More info [here](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/installation/kubernetes/helm/#application-and-server-properties).

Comment: Hi @Sabby! We have also tried to set this property but it's not taking into account.

Comment: I have updated the description. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: It is still unclear how you're passing it to the apps. Could you update the description with your stream definition?

Comment: I have updated my question. I hope it's understandable.